# how create 2d array in javascript with row and cel [[2,4,6], [4,16,32],[8,64,128]];?

Tags: javascript

How do I create a 2d array in JavaScript with row and cel?

Example output `[[2,4,6], [4,16,32],[8,64,128]];`

```js
var matrix = [],
    row = [],
   

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  row = [];
  for(var j = 2; j <= 6; j++) {
    row.push(j++);
    
  }
  matrix.push(row);
    
}
console.log('matrix', matrix[0],matrix[1],matrix[2]);

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
 console.log(matrix[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `const matrix = [[2,4,6], [4,16,32],[8,64,128]];`

Comment: Please fix the basic syntax error in the code (the `,` at the end of the second line should be a `;`). Separately from that, you're clearly pushing 2, 4, and then 6 into the array. So: How do you think you could change the value of what you're pushing?

Comment: var matrix = [],
    row = [],
    elem = 1;

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  row = [];
  for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    row.push(elem++);
  }
  matrix.push(row);
}

Answer (score 0):

```
/*If you notice it nothing but Array of arrays simple.
Example take 3 arrays*/
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = [4,5,6];
var arr3 = [8,9,0];`
//The combined array
var totalArr = [];
totalArr.push(arr1);
totalArr.push(arr2);
totalArr.push(arr3);`
/*Array.push() accepts the value that 
needs to be inserted into the array in question here that is totalArr 
Printing the array values*/
for(var i=0;i<totalArr.length;i++){
   for(var j=0;j<arr1.length;j++){
      console.log(totalArr[i][j]);
   }
}

/*on similar ground your code also works fine for me */
var matrix = [];
var row = [];


for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  row = [];
  for(var j = 2; j <= 6; j++) {
    row.push(j); 
  }
  matrix.push(row);
}
console.log('matrix', matrix[0],matrix[1],matrix[2]);

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    console.log(matrix[i][j]);
  }
}
console.log(matrix[0][1]); // gives 3 as o/p as expected
hope this helps!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

please use var matrix = [], row = []; instead of var matrix = [],
    row = [],